# How to delete folders in my local iCloud Drive folder

Tags: icloud

In my local iCloud Drive folder I have a lot of unused folders from old iPhone apps.
But I am not able to delete these folders.
Even `rm -rf` does not delete the folders.
The folder is in:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents
```

Any idea?